# Is there a way to forward declare covariance?

Tags: c++, covariance, forward-declaration

Suppose I have these abstract classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
  virtual Bar* bar() = 0;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  virtual Foo* foo() = 0;
};
```

Suppose further that I have the derived class `ConcreteFoo` and `ConcreteBar`. I want to covariantly refine the return type of the `foo()` and `bar()` methods like this:

```
class ConcreteFoo : public Foo
{
public:
  ConcreteBar* bar();
};

class ConcreteBar : public Bar
{
public:
  ConcreteFoo* foo();
};
```

This won't compile since our beloved single pass compiler does not know that `ConcreteBar` will inherit from `Bar`, and so that `ConcreteBar` is a perfectly legal covariant return type. Plain forward declaring `ConcreteBar` does not work, either, since it does not tell the compiler anything about inheritance.

Is this a shortcoming of C++ I'll have to live with or is there actually a way around this dilemma?

Comment: A lot us think of covariance as unecessary - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260757/when-is-c-covariance-the-best-solution which as far as I'm concerned has failed to provoke a compelling answer.

Comment: I am working on a project with tons of kloc of existing code. Simply by covariantly changing the return type of a few methods I was able to get rid of many static_casts. If I had a compelling solution to the above problem, I could get rid of even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fake it quite easily, but you lose the static type checking.  If you replace the `dynamic_casts` by `static_casts`, you have what the compiler is using internally, but you have no dynamic nor static type check:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
  Bar* bar();
protected:
  virtual Bar* doBar();
};

class Bar;
{
public:
  Foo* foo();
public:
  virtual Foo* doFoo();
};

inline Bar* Foo::bar() { return doBar(); }
inline Foo* Bar::foo() { return doFoo(); }

class ConcreteFoo;
class ConcreteBar;
class ConcreteFoo : public Foo
{
public:
  ConcreteBar* bar();
protected:
  Bar* doBar();
};

class ConcreteBar : public Bar
{
public:
   ConcreteFoo* foo();
public:
   Foo* doFoo();
};

inline ConcreteBar* ConcreteFoo::bar() { return &dynamic_cast<ConcreteBar&>(*doBar()); }
inline ConcreteFoo* ConcreteBar::foo() { return &dynamic_cast<ConcreteFoo&>(*doFoo()); }
```

Comment: This solution works, but surely won't win a beauty contest :)

Comment: If the participants are restricted to those solving the stated problem, I'm not so sure of the outcome :-)  You obviously can use the language provided covariance for one of the class, but I preferred to keep the symmetry.

Comment: @Tobias: I don't think that the original design with the complex dependencies would win a beauty contest either. :P

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't static polymorphism solve your problem? 
Feeding the base class with the derived class through template argument?
So the base class will know the derivative Type and declare a proper virtual?

Answer (score 3):

How about this.

```
template <class BarType>
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual BarType* bar() = 0;
};

template <class FooType>
class Bar
{
public:
    virtual FooType* foo() = 0;
};

class ConcreteBar;
class ConcreteFoo : public Foo<ConcreteBar>
{
public:
    ConcreteBar* bar();
};

class ConcreteBar : public Bar<ConcreteFoo>
{
public:
    ConcreteFoo* foo();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Covariance is based on inheritance diagram, so since you cannot declare

```
class ConcreteBar : public Bar;
```

hence no way to tell compiler about covariance.

But you can do it with help of templates, declare ConcretFoo::bar as template and later bounding allows you solve this problem

Comment: I know that you cannot forward declare inheritance. And templates won't help, either, since a template member function cannot be virtual.

Comment: Not exactly: here my sample that works!
<pre><code>
class ConcreteFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    template <class T>
    T* bar();
};
template <>
ConcreteBar* ConcreteFoo::bar<ConcreteBar>(){}

</code></pre>

Comment: Dewfy: Please include a working sample in your answer, I cannot construct one from your given code. http://codepad.org/xl4NTdQt

Comment: @Roger Pate done, look at http://codepad.org/xl4NTdQt#comment-ayWjjk4p sample works on msvc, g++

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's making ConcreteFoo a template rather than ConcreteFoo::bar as you first said.