# how to copy an inherited class from its base class pointer without splicing?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am having some trouble with trying to create a copy of a class from a pointer to its base class.  It is best illustrated through this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() { }
    virtual void test() { std::cout << "I am just the base class\n"; }
};

class First : public Base {
  public:
    First() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the First class\n"; }
};

class Second : public Base {
  public:
    Second() { }
    void test() { std::cout << "This is the Second class\n"; }
};

int main() {
  First *f = new First();
  Second *s = new Second();

  // First, I keep a vector of pointers to their base class
  std::vector<Base *> ptrs;
  ptrs.push_back(f);
  ptrs.push_back(s);
  ptrs[0]->test();    // Properly calls the implemented virtual class by inheritor
  ptrs[1]->test();    // Properly calls the implemented virtual class by inheritor

  // Now, I want to *copy* the class without it being spliced to just the base class
  // from the ptrs vector (not from 'f')
  First *f2 = new First(*ptrs[0]);
}
```

The error I end up getting is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘First::First(Base&)’
test.cpp:12: note: candidates are: First::First()
test.cpp:10: note:                 First::First(const First&)
```

Is there any way to cast this pointer to copy the full objected, and not just the base class?  Or do I need to store a pointer to the inheritor to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
First *f2 = 0;
if ( typeid(*ptrs[0]) == typeid(First))
   f2 = new First(*dynamic_cast<First*>(ptrs[0]));
```

That should work.

But a better approach is to have `clone()` virtual function in the base class, and implement it the derived class:

```
class Base 
{
  public:
    virtual ~Base() { } //virtual destructed added by me!
    virtual Base *clone() = 0;
};

class First : public Base 
{
  public:
    virtual First *clone() { /* implement it */ }  //Covariant return type
};
```

And

```
First *f2 = 0;
if ( typeid(*ptrs[0]) == typeid(First))
   f2 = ptrs[0]->clone(); //no need to use new
```

Two points to be noted:

- I have added virtual destructor to the Base class. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123044/when-should-your-destructor-be-virtual) to know why you *probably* need it.
- I have used different return type for `clone()` in the derived class. It is called [covariant return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260757/when-is-c-covariance-the-best-solution).

Answer (score 1):

```
First *fx=(First*)ptrs[0];
First *f2 = new First(*fx);
```