# How to call derived assignment operator from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

Given a pointer to an abstract base class `A*`, I want to copy or assign it (as the base class) and have the derived copy constructor or assignment operator called.  I understand copy constructors cannot be virtual, so presumably the copy constructor isn't an option for doing this, but the assignment operator is.  Still, it doesn't seem to work: the following code prints

```
assigned a
x!
destroyed b
destroyed b
```

which fails to assign b.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void x()=0;
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual A& operator=(const A& other) { cout << "assigned a" << endl; return *this;}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual B& operator=(const B& other)  { cout << "assigned b" << endl; return *this;}
    virtual void x() { cout << "x!" << endl; }
    virtual ~B() { cout << "destroyed b" << endl; }
};

int main() 
{ 
    A* a = new B(); 
    A* aa = new B(); 
    *aa=*a; 
    aa->x(); 
    delete a; 
    delete aa; 
    return 0;
}
```

How to do this?

**EDIT** this question has been correctly answered below, but it was the wrong question.  I shouldn't try to override the assignment operator because I don't want subclasses of A to assign *to one another*.  For the simpler answer (hopefully) see [C++ elegantly clone derived class by calling base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189838/c-elegantly-clone-derived-class-by-calling-base-class)

Comment: Not that it matters much, but the question asks about a **virtual base class** and the code does not have one.

Comment: I think you mean *abstract* base class, not "virtual" (which is a completely different thing). The abstractness of the base class is irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `B::operator=` **does not override** the one in `A`. Change it to

```
virtual A& operator=(const A& other)  { cout << "assigned b" << endl; return *this;}
```

and it will work. Also, try to use the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword when overriding member functions (requires C++11). The code won't compile if you don't override. In your case, it would have caught your mistake

> error: 'virtual B& B::operator=(const B&)' marked 'override', but does not override

PS: you were probably thinking about [covariant return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260757/when-is-c-covariance-the-best-solution). In order for it to work, the signature of your function has to be the same, except the return type. E.g., this will work:

```
virtual B& operator=(const A& other)  { cout << "assigned b" << endl; return *this;}
```

Comment: Ok that's good, but how would `B::operator=` access fields unique to `B` if it cannot guarantee that `const A& other` is an instance of `B`?

Comment: @SideshowBob You can test the result of a [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to see if `other` is really a `B`. But this should also make you think whether your design is sound.

Comment: The fact this is hard is indeed making me question my design.  Ultimately, I need to deep-copy a class from a base class pointer without knowing what the class really is.  Under the principle of encapsulation that's not an insane requirement, right?

Comment: @SideshowBob One solution is to use [double dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B) via a different function, call it `assign`.

Comment: That means giving all the derived classes an `assign` function (or `clone` would do the job in my case) when only one of them needs anything other than the default.  Is there a way to say `find the derived class assignment operator (which will be virtual if not default) and use it`?

Comment: @SideshowBob I think you can have a base class with a virtual `operator=`, then implement double dispatching with it. Basically you use `operator=` as you'd use `assign`. Scott Meyers has a very nice introduction to double dispatching in *More effective C++, Item 31*.