# P0847 deducing this - can it allow a generic clone without a need for CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp, type-deduction, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

[P0847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0847r5.html) proposes the possibility of using explicit `this` parameter for member functions.

Among other great goodies that this proposal brings, there is also the great new possibility for [CRTP without C, R and even T](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0847r5.html#crtp).

A common practice for implementing a generic `clone` in C++ is based on CRTP, see for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189838/c-elegantly-clone-derived-class-by-calling-base-class).

Given that we need `clone` to be `virtual` (or at least, behave as virtual), to allow:

```
Shape* pCopy = pShape->clone(); // get a copy of the correct runtime type
```

And given that the proposal is that a member function with an explicit this parameter **shall not be declared `virtual`.**

Would there still be a way to use P0847 in order to implement a *generic clone* with dynamic behavior and *without CRTP*?

Comment: Maybe a bit early to create that tag, no? :p

Comment: @cigien the tag would be needed at a certain point of time, now or later

Comment: Unless it comes out as `c++24`.  For now... `c++2b`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to go with @Eljay on that. No big deal I suppose. The tag name can be retroactively changed if needed, I think.

Comment: After looking at P0847 5.2.1, I think the answer to your question is **yes**, a "generic" clone could leverage this language feature to do a `clone`.  And the resulting code would be a lot more straightforward (for those of use who find CRTP turns our brains into a klein bottle pretzel).

Comment: @Eijay after reading Jarod's answer and thinking about it again I tend to agree that the answer is **no**, as P0847 can assist with deducing **the static type of `this`** but **not the dynamic type**. It means that a dynamic clone would still require either virtual function in each derived class or the fully fledged CRTP with the C, R and T. In cases where CRTP is used for deducing static type, P0847 would allow to replace CRTP with a templated method having an explicit this parameter, as presented in the paper.

Comment: I wish I had a compiler that had P0847 implemented so I could play with it.  Drat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

template deduction only uses static type, whereas `Clone` need dynamic type, and so `virtual`.

P0847 mostly allows to transform

```
template <typename T>
T* Foo(const T& obj);
// With Obj base of T
```

into

```
template <typename Self>
Self* Obj::Foo(this const Self& obj);
```

What you could do though is simplify the covariance with smart pointer.

```
struct Clonable
{
    virtual ~Clonable() = default;
    virtual Clonable* do_clone() const = 0;

    template <typename Self>
    std::unique_ptr<Self> clone(this const Self& self)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Self>(self.do_clone());
    }
};

struct MyClass : Clonable
{
    MyClass* do_clone() const override { return new MyClass(*this); }
};
```

But CRTP seems better as it allows to avoid to rewrite `do_clone` for each type.

(future reflection might simplify `Clonable`)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if this proposal permits an explicit `this` on a constructor.

If it did we could solves this.

```
struct clonable {
  icloneable const*(*do_clone)(icloneable const*) = 0;
  template<class Derived>
  clonable( this Derived& ):
    do_clone([](icloneable const* vself)->icloneable const*{
      return new Derived(*static_cast<Derived const*>(vself);
    })
  {}
  icloneable const* clone() const {
    return do_clone( this );
  }
};
```

this relies on the ability to have explicit this passed to constructors, and that explicit this parameter being the most-derived type.

We basically implemented a vtable (of one entry) ourselves.

Failing the ability to do this, you might have to wait for reflection.