# C++ polymorphism Storing Base Class pointer in a vector

Tags: c++11, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I have a base class and then two derived classes from it. I am using pointer of base class to store derived classes objects in Vector. Now I have to print the data stored in vector

how can I retrieve the objects from the vector.

How can I make sure to which derived class an object retrieved belongs.

```
    class CricketPlayer:public SlumsMember
{
    protected:
        int runsScored;
        int wicketsTaken;
        int catchesTaken;
    public:
        CricketPlayer(int rNo,string n,double theGpa,char typ,int rScore,int theWicketTaken,int theCatchTaken);
        int getRunsScored();
        int getWicketsTaken();
        int getCatchesTaken();

};

    CricketPlayer::CricketPlayer(int rNo,string n,double theGpa,char typ,int rScore,int theWicketTaken,int theCatchTaken):
                   SlumsMember(rNo,n,theGpa,typ)
                   {
                      runsScored=rScore;
                      wicketsTaken=theWicketTaken;
                      catchesTaken=theCatchTaken;
                   }



    int CricketPlayer::getRunsScored()
    {
        return (runsScored);

    }
    int CricketPlayer::getWicketsTaken()
    {
        return (wicketsTaken);
    }
    int CricketPlayer::getCatchesTaken()
    {
        return(catchesTaken);
    }

class FootballPlayer:public SlumsMember
{
 protected: 
    int goalsScored;
    int assists;
    int interceptions;
 public:

    FootballPlayer(int rNo,string n,double theGpa,char typ,int theGoalsScored,int theAssists,int theInterceptions);
    int getGoalsScored();
    int getAssists();
    int getInterceptions();

};

   FootballPlayer::FootballPlayer(int rNo,string n,double theGpa,char typ,int theGoalsScored,int theAssists,int theInterceptions):
                    SlumsMember(rNo,n,theGpa,typ)
                    {
                            goalsScored=theGoalsScored;
                            assists=theAssists;
                            interceptions=theInterceptions;
                    }

    int FootballPlayer::getGoalsScored()
    {
            return(goalsScored);

    }
    int FootballPlayer::getAssists()
    {
        return(assists);

    }
    int FootballPlayer::getInterceptions()
    {
            return(interceptions);
    }
```

Here I am using vector to store  objects inside a vector.

int main() {

```
vector<SlumsMember> members;

SlumsMember *slumsMember;

                    slumsMember=new FootballPlayer(rNo,name,gpa,ch,a,b,c);


                    slumsMember=new CricketPlayer(rNo,name,gpa,ch,a,b,c);





            members.push_back(*slumsMember);

SlumsMember *mbr;
 for(int i=0;i<members.size();i++)
 {
    mbr=members[i];

  //How to make sure to which base class an object retrieved belongs to and how to access it.

 }     







return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried even accessing through  members[i]->getType() as well but nothing happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit...

```
class SlumsMember
{
```

try this... make the getWicketsTaken function virtual in the base class

```
public:
   virtual int getWicketsTaken();

   int rollNumber;
   string name;
   double gpa;
   char type;
};



class CricketPlayer:public SlumsMember
{
public:
```

overriding can help with type overload prevention

```
   int getWicketsTaken() override;

   int runsScored;
   int wicketsTaken;
   int catchesTaken;
};



class FootballPlayer: public SlumsMember
{
Then you can override the getWicketsTaken in this class too

int getWicketsTaken() override;

public: 
   int goalsScored;
   int assists;
   int interceptions;
};

int main() {
   vector<SlumsMember*> members;
```

Please note that on the next line you should receive a compiler error if the value that you give it is not a type of slumsmember.

```
   members.push_back(new FootballPlayer(rNo,name,gpa,ch,a,b,c));
   members.push_back(new CricketPlayer(rNo,name,gpa,ch,a,b,c));

   SlumsMember *mbr;
   for(int i=0;i<members.size();i++)
   {
      mbr=members[i];
      //How to make sure to which base class an object retrieved belongs to and how to access it.
      int rollNumber = mbr->rollNumber;
      double gpa = mbr->gpa;
```

etc... and Don't forget to free your objects at the end at some point so that you don't get memory leaks

```
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: But did you read the rest of the answer? Feel free to ask questions if anything in my answer is not clear

Comment: Please note that I changed
vector<SlumsMember> members;
to
vector<SlumsMember*> members;

Comment: Why I cannot retrieve the members of the derived class such as of the CricketPlayer  with  mbr->getWicketsTaken()  it is getter of my CricketPlayer derived class.

Comment: is the getter public or protected

Comment: getter is public but member is protected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150242/discussion-between-programmingninja-and-strange-graphs).

Comment: this article can help too. Look at my edits. they should give the answer. You need to make it virtual

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932391/virtual-override-or-both-c

Comment: do i need to have all the getter virtual, or add a virtual print method in the base as well as in the derived classes

Comment: it depends. Maybe read up on best practices for virtual functions in base classes. This answer should get you by on the error that you were receiving though I think :).

Comment: done and completed as you suggested thank you so so much

Comment: Seems to me an odd design that allows one to ask how many wickets a footballplayer has taken.