# Is the method overridden or overloaded?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, overloading

We have two classes.

```
class A{
public:
  void fun(){
     cout<<"Parent\n";
  }
};
class B:public A{
public:
  void fun(){
     cout<<"Child\n";
  }
};
```

I am trying to figure out if the function `fun()` will be considered `overloaded` or `overridden`.
I tried using the `override` keyword and it says that the method is not overridden. But I wonder if the `override` keyword will only work if the function in the parent class is written as `virtual` and if the function can be considered as overridden in the case mentioned above.

Also, I want to know if overriding a method **always** means late-binding/runtime-polymorphism?

Comment: Override. An overload occurs only when the methods have the same signature (but varies in the parameters provided).

Comment: Neither. It's shadowed.

Comment: @Urmzd isn't it like a non-virtual method can't be overridden?

Comment: @rustyx can you explain a bit? some references?

Comment: Only virtual methods can be overridden with the `override` keyword. The term `overridden` is, itself, overloaded in the language says, because it sometimes refers to this situation: where nothing is really overriden, but if you call `fun()` through a pointer to `B` you get the subclass, and if you call `fun()` through a pointer to `A` you get the superclass's `fun()`, even if the pointer is really pointing to a superclass of an actual instance of `B`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have corrected the reference.

Comment: @rustyx I guess we could argue all day and all night, should we choose to do so, but that is an override, plain and simple. It's *not* shadowing.

Comment: @AdrianMole - It is not an override. The person here is trying to learn C++, so it is **better** to stick to the C++ terminology. There is no override in this code. Only one method hiding another. Plain and simple.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can't find a C+ reference, so I'll just remove my reference until I can. Regardless of the language, the same concepts apply. Shadowing can be boiled to a entire redefinition of some method, whereas overriding involves the redefinition of the implementation of some method. Hence, this would be considered overriding. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932391/should-i-use-virtual-override-or-both-keywords).

Comment: @Urmzd - It's **not** an override. C++ uses its own specific terminology. You would only confuse the OP (and yourself, since `virtual` doesn't cause or prevent shadowing) by insisting on porting terminology from other domains.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Meh. I guess I still need more 'updating' on *current* C++ terminology. Try as I might, I can't find an actual reference to overriding a non-virtual function. (But, in the old days, that *was* called an override.)

Comment: @AdrianMole - I learned C++03 from books written in the late nineties. The terminology hasn't changed since. It's nothing modern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B::fun` *neither* overloads *nor* overrides `A::fun`. It *hides* it. It's not an override because you can still get the `A::fun` behavior on a `B` by treating it as an `A`

```
B x;
A &y = x;
y.fun(); // outputs Parent
```

When you try to access the `fun` method through the `A` interface, you get the `Parent` behavior. Were `A::fun` declared `virtual`, *then* `B::fun` would override it and the `fun` method accessed through the `A` interface would output `Child`.

The difference between overloading and hiding is not clear here because the argument lists are the same, but consider the hierarchy

```
struct A {
    void foo(int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
};
struct B : A {
    void foo(std::string const &s) { std::cout << std::quoted(s) << "\n"; }
};
```

If `B::foo` just *overloaded* `A::foo` then this would work

```
B x;
x.foo(5);
```

But it does not. Note that `x` still *has* the `foo(int)` method.

```
A &y = x;
y.foo(5); // works
```

You just can't get to it through the `B` interface. This is because overload resolution is only done among the set of members declared in the same class. If a class doesn't declare a member of the name, then it goes to the base classes, but if the class does declare the name and none of them match, the resolution just fails right there. (I.e. removing `B::foo` would make `x.foo(5)` work.)

You can *request* overloading instead of hiding from the language with a `using` directive, but again overriding is impossible unless `A::fun` is `virtual` (and `B::fun` would need to have the same argument list as `A::fun`).

```
struct B : A {
    using A::foo;
    void foo(std::string const &s) { std::cout << std::quoted(s) << "\n"; }
};
```

(P.S. Regarding the comments, the technical term in C++ is indeed *hiding*. *Shadowing* may be the word used for this behavior in other languages, but the C++ standard uses "hiding".)