# I am getting LNK2005, LNK2001 and LNK1120 while using virtual function in my Program

Tags: c++, oop, namespaces, lnk2001, lnk2005

I am a beginner so this problem might seem trivial to you.
So I have the following files:

- base.h
- derived.h
- base.cpp
- derived.cpp
- TestCpp.cpp

**base.h**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace App
{
    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual void Print();
    };
}
```

**base.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"

namespace App
{
}
```

**derived.h**

```
#include "base.h"

class Derived : public App::Base
{
public:
    void Print();
};
```

**derived.cpp**

```
#include "derived.h"

void Derived::Print()
{
    std::cout << "This works!! form Derived class\n";
}
```

and at last
**TestCpp.cpp**

```
#include "derived.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Derived d;
    d.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following Linker error:
[image]

I don't know what it is I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: You have clearly realized that you need to provide an actual *definition* for `Derived::Print()`, so what makes you think things are different for `Base::Print()`?

Comment: You need to add a definition of `virtual void Print();` in `Base` or make it pure virtual by writing `virtual void Print() = 0;` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/17732522).

Comment: @user17732522 that did work out. I thought if you use the keyword "virtual" you had to skip the definition in the base class.

Comment: @AnirudhKanaparthy A _pure virtual_ function doesn't need a definition, but simply a _virtual_ function does, because you can still create a `Base` object directly and call `.Print()` on it. Which function definition should then be called? If you make it pure virtual, the class becomes an _abstract class_, for which only derived instances can be created, so the definition isn't required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you've only **declared** the virtual function `Print` in class `Base` but not **defined** it.

And from **C++03 Standard: 10.3 Virtual functions [class.virtual]**

> A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is required (3.2).

So the way to solve this problem would be to either implement/**define** the `virtual` member function `Print` in class `Base` or make it **pure virtual** by replacing the declaration with `virtual void Print() = 0;` inside class `Base`

##### Solution 1

**Base.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"

namespace App
{
    void Base::Print()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Solution 1 [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/sCLe9td23)

##### Solution 2

**Base.h**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace App
{
    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual void Print() = 0;
    };
}
```

Solution 2 [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/PybJfiqCe)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a definition for `Print()` in the `base.cpp` file:

```
namespace App
{
    void Base::Print() { }
}
```

It may not have anything inside it, but it should be there.

Or indicate `Print()` to be defined in the derived class by making it pure:

```
virtual void Print() = 0;
```

Any one of the 2 options work. Also in your derived class it's better to make `Print()` as `override`: ([Click here to know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932391/should-i-use-virtual-override-or-both-keywords))

```
class Derived : public App::Base
{
public:
    void Print() override;
};
```