# How does virtual dispatch interact with covariant return types?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subclass

With C++ support for covariant return types, you can write the following:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

...

class A {
 public:
  A(Base* b) : b_(b) {}
  virtual Base* Method() { return b_; }

 private:
  Base* b_;
}

class B : public A {
 public:
  B(Derived* b) : A(b) {}
  // Return `Derived*` type so callers can access functionality specific to
  // `Derived` (i.e., not in `Base`).
  Derived* Method() override {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>);
    // Need to call `A::Method()` since `b_` is private.
    // Alternatively, we can make `b_` protected and access it directly.
    return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(A::Method());
  }
}
```

It seems like in most cases that use covariant return types, the derived class's method (`B::Method()` above) will just do a dynamic cast and return the narrower pointer type. It will not do anything else.

**Given that assumption, is it generally better to *not* use virtual dispatch (i.e., remove the `virtual` and `overridden` keywords) for `Method()` to improve performance?** After all, any generic code that operates on an `A*` type will have to use the `Base*` type to store the return value of `A::Method()` (even if the real type of the object that the pointer points to is `Derived`), but as long `Base` uses virtual dispatch properly, then the correct methods will be called on `Base*` whether they are `Base`'s methods or `Derived`'s methods.

Comment: Where did you get that example from? See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260757/when-is-c-covariance-the-best-solution) or [here](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/20/covariance-and-contravariance/) for some examples of what covariance is supposed to be used for.

Comment: Your use of `static_assert` does not guarantee that `A::Method()` actually returns a `Derived` object. Your `dynamic_cast` will still fail if `A::Method()` returns a `Base` object (or other `Base`-derived object that is not derived from `Derived`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is a good point. To add context, in the project I am trying to extend, basically the `A` class has a class member of type `Base*`. `A` will initialize it to point to an object of type `Base` whereas `B` will initialize it to point to an object of type `Derived`.

Comment: @user17732522 Take a look at my updated code. I'm trying to extend a project that has a bunch of classes that all reference each other, so I'm struggling a bit to subclass various types to use my own functionality. That's why I am looking into covariant return types. Some classes have an `A` and expect it to return a `Base*` whereas other classes have a `B` and expect it to return a `Derived*` so that they do not need to do dynamic casts themselves (since they may also call methods on `Derived` that `Base` does not have).

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like in most cases that use covariant return types, the derived class's method (B::Method() above) will just do a dynamic cast and return the narrower pointer type. It will not do anything else.

I would not be so sure about that.

These two features serve two different purposes:

- `virtual` methods allow virtual dispatch - runtime choice of the code to execute based on the runtime type of the caller.
- return type covariance leverages the type system to further constraint the return type as long as the "minimal API" given by `Base` is satisfied. This is compile-time check.

I would strongly argue that `B::Method` should not exist in it's current form at all, let's take this hierarchy:

```
struct Base{
    virtual ~Base()=default;
};
struct D1:Base{};
struct D2:Base{};


struct A {
  virtual Base* Method() { return new D1{}; }
};

struct B1 : A {
  D1* Method() override {
    return dynamic_cast<D1*>(A::Method());
  }
};
struct B2 : A {
  D2* Method() override {
    return dynamic_cast<D2*>(A::Method());
  }
};
```

and this usage:

```
#include <cassert>

int main()
{   
    B1 b1;
    B2 b2;

    A* a = &b1;
    assert(a->Method()!=nullptr);
    a = &b2;
    assert(a->Method()==nullptr);
}
```

That seems a little strange, how would you write the documentation of this `A::Method`? What could it be used for? A filter maybe?

I think the more common example, at least from what I've seen, is that the derived method produces a derived result on its own. Take for example hiearchy of `Request`, `Response` with `virtual Response* Request::process` method. Special requests likely return special responses.

**To answer your question:**
If you remove `virtual`, you lose virtual dispatch, if the user code can do with static polymorphism, sure. Just give it some though beforehand, in my experience, if you start replacing member variables of type `Base*` with `T` in some `Foo`, the templated code needed to handle storage of these now heterogenous `Foo<T>` tends to spread rather quickly. And for what, performance only? Surely you are considering this only because you measured the code and it is a clear bottleneck in your application.